# How do I set default host for url helpers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, configuration

I would like to do something like this

```
config.default_host = 'www.subdomain.example.com'
```

in some of my configuration files, so that `object_url` helpers (`ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`) produce links beginning with http://www.subdomain.example.com

I have tried to search the docs but I did not find anything except `ActionMailer` docs and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Configuration.html which is not useful for me, because I do not know in which pat to look. Is there a place which describes the whole structure of Rails::Initializer.config?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`asset_host` doesn't work for urls

You need to override `default_url_options` in your `ApplicationController` (at least in Rails 3)

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    if Rails.env.production?
      {:host => "myproduction.com"}
    else  
      {}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Or you can set in your production.rb
# production.rb
    config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'myproduction.com' }

Comment: hello, sorry to reopen it, but I have a quick question : can we put multiple addresses in :host value ?

Comment: Any updates as to how this might work in rails 5 engines?

Comment: Setting `config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'myproduction.com' }` is not thread safe. It's recommended to override the method in ApplicationContorller, which is.

Answer (score 54):

Define the default host in your environment config:

```
# config/environments/staging.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # ...
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'preview.mydomain.com'
  # ...
end
```

Then you can create a URL anywhere in your app:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.widgets_url()
```

Or include the URL helpers in your class:

```
class MyLib
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def make_a_url
    widgets_url
  end
end
```

If you don't define the default host, you will need to pass it as an option:

```
widgets_url host: (Rails.env.staging? ? 'preview.mydomain.com' : 'www.mydomain.com')
```

It's also useful to specify things like the protocol:

```
widgets_url protocol: 'https'
```

Comment: Currently its `Rails.application.default_url_options`, without .routes

Comment: @MarcinAdamczyk You mean in Rails 4?

Comment: For sure its in Rails 4, I dont remember about this option in Rails 3

Answer (score 33):

Another way is to set it like this

```
# config/production.rb
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'myproduction.com' }
```

Comment: I had the same experience as @CHawk.

Comment: This is what worked for me with Rails 7.x, thank you! 

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 6.1 (at least), application-wide default_url_options can be set as follows:

```rb
# config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

Rails.application.configure do
 # ...
end
```

See: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29992#issuecomment-761892658

Answer (score 4):

You can easily set `:host` or/and `:only_path` parameter for every url_helper.
 
 `yours_url(params, :host => "http://example.com", :only_path => Rails.env.test?)`

This way you are not setting global default_url_options in your environments, unless you want that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `*_url` helpers use the server's configured host name. So for example if my Apache installation is accepting requests for this Rails app at `http://www.myapp.com/` then Rails will use that address. That's why the `*_url` methods in a development environment point to `http://localhost:3000` by default.

The asset host suggested in the previous answer will only affect the `image_tag`, `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_link_tag` helpers.

Comment: This is a good idea, but at least in my case it does not work. I have virtual server with ServerName subdomain.example.com and *_url helpers use only example.com. 

I have also tried to look at environment variables and I am getting HTTP_HOST as subdomain.example.com, so I am pretty sure that it is correct.

Answer (score -5):

NSD's solution is how I do it, but I had to add a block to make it work with https:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
  (request ? request.protocol : 'http://') +  "www.subdomain.example.com"
}
```

Comment: Asset host is for the asset pipeline, not the routes of the application.

Comment: Who is NSD, and where did you place this code? I assume it was in either the application controller or one of the environment-specific files in /config/environments. As this is a site which is provided to help people solve problems, clarity is very important.

Comment: NSD was a commenter who's post has been removed.

Answer (score -10):

There's this, but I'm not terribly sure if they're the helpers you're referring to:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = "assets.example.com"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Comment: I mean helpers as in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

I have added this to my question.

Comment: `asset_host` deals with the host for the asset pipeline, not the application's routes.