# How to set the ActionMailer default_url_options's :host dynamically to the request's hostname?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set the :host for action mailer default url options.

I have the below set in all the environment files

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => "localhost"
}
```

I want to make it more dynamic by providing the request host.

when I try to set it by

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => request.domain
}
```

OR

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => request.env["SERVER_NAME"]
}
```

It throws error... doesn't recognize "request" object

is there any way I can set this to the request host, not by hardcoding...?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is also possible to set a default host that will be used in all mailers by setting the :host option in the default_url_options hash

in an `application_controller.rb` add:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    { host: request.host_with_port }
  end
end
```

Source: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options

Alternatively, you can pass the `request` when calling the mailer function from the controller

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def welcome_email(user, request)
    @user = user
    @url  = user_url(@user, host: request.host_with_port ) # do this for each link
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
end
```

Source : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-with-named-routes

Comment: ActionMailer::Base does not have access to the request object.

Comment: The before filter method works, but is not thread-safe, making it only good for situations that involve a single domain.

Comment: Before filter method - bye 'config.action_mailer.default_url_options' per environment! :)

Comment: @BradWerth Could you explain a bit more about why this works only with apps that use a single domain?

Comment: @pixelearth sorta like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587612/example-of-something-that-is-not-thread-safe-in-rails, but for the host

Comment: @BradWerth is correct, I've updated this answer to be thread safe

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE: use the selected response, since this isn't thread safe.

You can create a default filter like this:

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter :mailer_set_url_options

...

def mailer_set_url_options
  ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
end
```

(source: http://www.cherpec.com/2009/06/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-default_url_optionshost/)

Comment: Apparently (and infuriatingly) this isn't allowed anymore. I get this error: `RuntimeError (You can no longer call ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options directly. You need to set config.action_mailer.default_url_options. If you are using ActionMailer standalone, you need to include the routing url_helpers directly.)`

Comment: Not sure about that @nathan.f77.  I am able to set it with: `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = {:host => request.host_with_port}`

Comment: @SooDesuNe that's been deprecated now.  You can't set it directly anymore.

Comment: So what's the solution? It seems to me that, while it's useful to be able to set things in initializers via the config object, there should always be a way to modify the configuration after ActionMailer has been initialized... But this seems to still work for me as is in Rails 3.0.9 so I guess that works for now...

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say even with the newly released rails 3.2, this method works perfectly for me. Using subdomains, this was a damn life saver. Thanks!

Comment: Use this solution which is threadsafe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails

Answer (score 6):

the problem is these are initializers, they are run when the rails stack loads, and not when you call active mailer.

but you don't have to use the default_url, you can just pass the hostname into the url_for/named routes in each of your mailer views.  The default just avoids having to do that.

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html  section on generating urls.