# Changing backlink URL in Devise Mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When the user requests a reset-link sent to his email using Devise views, he receives an email  with this content:

> Hello example@gmail.com!
>   Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.
>   Change my password
>   (which points to)
>   localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=some_token
>   If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.
>   Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.

Now, this is all cool and dandy, except when I host the rails server on a different port, say

```
rails server -p 5678
```

Then the link **still** points to `localhost:3000`.

I know about `request.ip` and `request.port`, but I cannot find out where to change the Devise mailer objects. The relevant part of the mail-template used for this mail is

```
<%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %>
```

After debugging, it seems `@resource` is a `User`-object and this contains no URL.

Long story short: **How can I make the url (ip/port part) of Devise mails be dynamic?**

Comment: There are various ways to use the current host and ip in mailer urls. One among them is explained nicely in [this article](http://makandracards.com/makandra/1353-make-actionmailer-use-the-current-request-host-and-protocol-for-url-generation). Just follow this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the ActionMailer default\_url\_options's :host dynamically to the request's hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432712/how-to-set-the-actionmailer-default-url-optionss-host-dynamically-to-the-reque)