# Unexpected behavior with resource_url on Nginx and Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

I have a simple unicorn+nginx setup on cpanel, deployed with capistrano. The nginx.conf server block looks like this:

```
server {
  error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
  listen 123.456.789.0;
  server_name my.dev.site.com www.my.dev.site.com;
  access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/my.dev.site.com-bytes_log bytes_log;
  access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/my.dev.site.com combined;
  root /home/me/sites/dev/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_dev_site;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

Under this setup, any reference to a resource like `User` yields odd behavior with the url helpers.

`<%= users_path %>` becomes `my.dev.site.com/users` as expected.

`<%= users_url %>` becomes `unicorn_dev_site/users`.

What's causing this, and what are the differences between these two helper methods that prompts this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your proxying.  The `*_path` helpers generate strings of the form

```
/path
```

while the `*_url` helpers generate strings like

```
http(s)://h.o.s.t/path
```

So thanks to your proxy setup, by the time a request gets to Rails, it's been tweaked so that the host is listed as `http://unicorn_dev_site`, which Rails faithfully replicates in the URLs it generates.

That said, there's usually no need to use `*_url` helpers instead of `*_path` helpers unless you have multiple hosts.  If you want to use them, though, you have a couple options:  You can [set the default host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails) in your controllers, and you can also set it on a per-URL basis with the `:host` option to [url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for) (I expect you can extend this pretty easily to the `*_url` helpers, but I don't know that for sure).

Anyway - hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I solved this changing the `proxy_pass` name so rails would get the right one.