# Routing errors while processing URL(s) without a http prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We render HTML within a certain page and certain links don't have a http prefix (e.g. foo.com/bar) when you click on it throws a routing error. Is there a easier way to navigate to the right URL in such cases

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the link_to takes care of you in this regard. You say html, so I assume we can't use ERB code, so you'll have to hardcode the links into the HTML.

Make sense?

Of course without any html code or routes.rb code, I can't tell you whether or not there isn't anything wrong with your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use absolute links within your application? Navigating to just "/bar" on that case would be fine.

If you use the link_to helper function on your views, it should rely on url_for which by default generates relative paths.

If you need absolute paths, you can specify a default host on your application ([How do I set default host for url helpers in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails)) or specify it on the host option for the url_for function (http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for).

Comment: the code is rendered as foo.bar.html_safe and the link is within the content, not sure how to fix it.

Comment: So you generate the content on the backend of your application? You can import the helper and do it from there as well.

Comment: the content is external and I don't have any control over it.