# How can I access to *_url routes in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

If I trying access to routes helpers via  `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` everything ok, while I'm using *_path routes (article_path, note_path, etc.). But I need use *_url routes(articles_url, note_url, etc.). In this case I'm getting **missing host** error.

Rails version is 3.2.12

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails)

Comment: Are there any better solutions? I have 4 environments and sets all of they in application controller it's not a good idea. They are sets in ```/config/environments/*``` files too.

Comment: I use a global variable like `HOST` and set it in `environment.rb`  for each environment. Then in controller I can do  `def default_url_options :host => HOST end`