# Specifying rails 4 host per environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using `Rails 4.0.0` and `Ruby 2.0.0`

I was looking at my `_urls` and `_paths` in my rails console and noticed

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > app.host
 => "www.example.com"
2.0.0p247 :001 > app.root_url
 => "http://www.example.com/"
```

Is setting the `host` to `www.example.com` just default behavior upon `rails c` startup or is there a config somewhere that sets this domain?  If so, how do I set the `app.host` variable/config per environment?

Comment: Check if [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails) helps

Answer (score 0):

In the Rails 4 console, `app.host` and the like access an "integration session": It is seemingly a placeholder for the console to work completely. Apparently, the app host is not configurable. See the Railties gem.

Exert from v4.0.2: `railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/console/app.rb`

```
module Rails
  module ConsoleMethods
    def app(create=false)
      @app_integration_instance = nil if create
      @app_integration_instance ||= new_session do |sess|
        sess.host! "www.example.com"
      end
    end

    def new_session
      app = Rails.application
      session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(app)
      yield session if block_given?
      session
    end
  end
end
```

The `new_session` method allows to choose the host, though.