# Host is "thin" instead of "www.whateverdomain.com"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, thin

I'm running Thin and nginx to serve up my rails app. Everything is working fine, except that the root_url helper method returns "thin" as the domain. So `root_url(subdomain: "foo")` in a controller returns `foo.thin` instead of `foo.mydomain.com`.

The only similar questions on SO advise checking the environment in the controller and setting the host based on that, but I'm sure this is supposed to be handled automatically. Is there something nginx and/or thin isn't passing to Rails that's needed to infer the host?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails

Comment: @ArieShaw I don't believe so. That question is asking how to manually set the host. I'm trying to make sure it's detected automatically, as I assume it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to preserve the host being passed from nginx to Thin with this:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

in the proxy pass block. i.e.:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app_upstream;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    # ...
}
```