# Rails application behind proxy, with SSL, renders paths as "http://"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, proxy, unicorn

To start with, this sounds more like a bug then anything else.

My rails application is served by Unicorn. Then, using Nginx as a reverse proxy, I serve the application to the outside world using SSL.

So far so good, no problem. I'm using relative paths (Restful path helpers), so there should be no problem to produce this (for https://www.example.com):

```
new_entry_path => https://www.example.com/entries/new
```

This works fine in most cases.

The problem however appears when in a controller I try to redirect to a "show" action (using resources), let's say after a successful update (suppose Entry with id 100):

```
redirect_to @entry, flash: {success: "Entry has been updated"}
```

or

```
redirect_to entry_path(@entry), flash: {success: "Entry has been updated"}
```

they both produce a redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/entries/100 # missing 's' in https...
```

instead of

```
/entries/100 # implying https://www.example.com/entries/100
```

As far as I've noticed, this only happens with `show` action and only in controller redirects.

I'm bypassing this by doing something horrible and disgusting:

```
redirect_to entry_url(@entry).sub(/^http\:/,"https:"), flash: {success: "Entry has been updated"}
```

Has anyone ever confronted something similar? Any ideas will be gratefully accepted...

Comment: have your tried setting the default host? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails

Comment: I've seen that, but I'm trying to make the object_path helpers work, not the object_url helpers... Is this going to help me?

Comment: I believe so since `redirect_to` uses `url_for` [under the hood](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e006d5076a393c827fba69bf72bc36b7abf921b/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L65)

Comment: Btw. what does `ENV["HTTP_HOST"]` output on your server?

Comment: running it in ERB it gives out nil... I have however found a good workaround in Nginx, which I'll post as answer, but it's not 100% satisfactory... "object_path" should be `"/objects/nnn"`, not `"http://whatever/objects/nnn"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I've managed to get a workaround by adding a rewrite rule to Nginx, under plain http:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$  https://www.example.com/$1? permanent;
```

Which redirects all plain `http` requests to the `https` server.

**Update:**

Apparently, as I want the app not to care about how the front web server is serving it, it's up to the same web server to "clean the mess" of redirections the app by itself cannot handle unless it's been specifically configured (not desired). So, I will stick to this answer (workaround rather...)

**UPDATE**
Following papirtiger's answer, I saw that I ended up missing the flashes, which should be added to the overriding `redirect_to` as a parameter.

But I've found a way to do my life a lot easier, simply by overriding a different function, that is called from within `redirect_to`.

```
def _compute_redirect_to_location(options) #:nodoc:
    case options
    # The scheme name consist of a letter followed by any combination of
    # letters, digits, and the plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-")
    # characters; and is terminated by a colon (":").
    # See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.1
    # The protocol relative scheme starts with a double slash "//".
    when /\A([a-z][a-z\d\-+\.]*:|\/\/).*/i
        options
    ## WHEN STRING: THIS IS REMOVED TO AVOID ADDING PROTOCOL AND HOST ##
    # when String
    #   request.protocol + request.host_with_port + options
    when :back
        request.headers["Referer"] or raise RedirectBackError
    when Proc
        _compute_redirect_to_location options.call
    else
        url_for(options)
    end.delete("\0\r\n")
end
```

Thus, without having to change anything else in my code, I have a working relative redirect.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. By default Rails will use the current protocol for the `*_url` helpers.

We use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) as web server and [unicorn](https://unicorn.bogomips.org/) as application server. Nginx takes the request, unwrapps the SSL part and then passes it on to unicorn. Hence, unicorn always receives a `http` request. If we now want Rails to know about the original protocol, we can need to add the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

Example config:

```
upstream app {
    server unix:/var/run/myserver/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  myserver;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/myserver.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/myserver.key";

    root /myserver/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
    sendfile on;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; # <--- will be used
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
   }
}
```

Comment: I've solved a similar issue but using apache2 as the web server adding `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"` to the configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think [`force_ssl`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html) is what you are looking for.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?

  def ssl_configured?
    !Rails.env.development?
  end
end
```

---

**Edit**, if you really want to do redirects to relative paths you could always create your own helper:

```
module ActionController
  module RelativeRedirectingHelper
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    include AbstractController::Logger
    include ActionController::RackDelegation
    include ActionController::UrlFor

    def redirect_to_relative(path, response_status = 302) #:doc:
      raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to nil!") unless options
      raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to a parameter hash!") if options.is_a?(ActionController::Parameters)
      raise AbstractController::DoubleRenderError if response_body

      self.status        = response_status
      self.location      = path
      self.response_body = "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.h(location)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
    end
  end
end
```

This is a quick'n'dirty copy paste job . Will take a little more effort if you want have the same signature as `redirect_to`

Comment: This is another workaround... But I don't mean for the application to "care" if it's ssl or not, I leave to the reverse proxy to do the ssl-thingy... What I'm looking for, is for `something_path` to work as `something_path` and not as `something_url`...

Comment: `redirect_to` will try to make it an absolute url since according to the current version of the HTTP/1.1 standard, RFC 2616, the value of the Location header must be an absolute URI.

Comment: You could always make your own redirect helper, take a look at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e006d5076a393c827fba69bf72bc36b7abf921b/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L65

Comment: Added example of redirect helper

Comment: I see your point... So there is no *legitimate* working solution other than using the proxy to do the dirty work. I understand your points perfectly and it seems RFC get in the way of what I'm trying to do. Upvoting for the great answer nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: No Ruby knowledge here, but there is such a thing as Protocol Relative URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just

Comment: @Melvyn, thanks for the tip. I've updated my answer to use relative redirects.

Comment: @papirtiger, thanks a lot, your assistance has been more than valuable. You can check my updated answer to see what I've done.