# Rails application without virtual host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I need to host two rails app in one server and I don't have so many domain names.  So I followed http://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/redmine-ruby-on-rails-without-virtual-hosts/ which works.  The root url changes from http://{virtual-host}/ to http://{main-domain}/railsapp/

My problem is when I do something like:

```
redirect_to root_path
```

I am redirected to http://{main-domain}/ instead of http://{main-domain}/railsapp/ as expected.  I can of course

```
redirect_to '/railsapp'
```

but is there a better way than to repeat /railsapp all over the app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to configure `config.relative_url_root`

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root