# Setting default host for URL helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, configuration

I'm creating a Reddit sort of site to learn Rails but I'm using subdomains instead of longer URLs for subreddits (ie funny.reddit.com instead of reddit.com/r/funny).

For development, I'm using http://vcap.me (redirects to localhost) to work with subdomains as I think plain localhost doesn't work with subdomains.

I'm having some difficulties linking to these subdomains. I can do

```
subreddit_url = url_for(host: "http://vcap.me", subdomain: subreddit.subdomain)
```

and works just fine. However, I don't want to hardcode the host since I want to eventually push to Heroku and the host will be different. I tried doing something similar to [How do I set default host for url helpers in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails), more specifically

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 def default_url_options
  if Rails.env.development?
   {:host => "http://vcap.me"}
  else  
   {}
  end
 end
end
```

but my url_for returns '/' when I do

```
url_for(subdomain: subreddit.subdomain)
```

I've also tried setting only_path: false but it also doesn't do anything.

Using Rails 4.2 Ruby 2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't really matter because you can't use subdomains on free Heroku apps anyway.