# How to setup default host for link_to helper in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

Currently I am using the old fashioned way to make `link_to`

```
<%= link_to 'Attend Survey', {:controller => :survey, :action => :get_personal_data}, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

And the issue is that I have non default host (lets say it is something like `/~foo/bar`) for whole application.

I have added `config.relative_url_root = '/~foo/bar'` to the `production.rb` and all assets are shown correctly the only thing left is `link_to` helper which gives me still default host `/` route.

I may be doing something wrong but all solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails) answer didn't work in that particular case or due to Rails 4 changes.

**EDIT**
Due to production env `RAILS_ENV=production rake routes` gives me

```
         Prefix Verb URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
  survey_context GET  /survey/context(.:format)        survey#get_personal_data
                 GET  /survey/selfesteem/:id(.:format) survey#get_self_esteem
    survey_index GET  /survey/index(.:format)          survey#index
survey_thank_you GET  /survey/thank_you(.:format)      survey#thank_you
                 POST /survey/context(.:format)        survey#create_person
                 POST /survey/selfesteem/:id(.:format) survey#create_self_esteem_for_person
            root GET  /                                survey#index
```

Comment: That should work indeed. Could it be the `~` sign in your path that confuses Rails?

Comment: Well maybe, but unfortunately there is no way for me to skip it currently.

Comment: Can you do `rake routes` and post the output?

Comment: seems to still be an issue with rails - > https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5122