# How to "link_to" full path in rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

This is the code i have

```
<a <%= link_to "open your box", gig_path(@gig), class: "mcnButton", target: "_blank", style: "font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: 0px;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;"%></a>
```

from the above `<%= link_to "open your box", gig_path(@gig)`

Note `gig_path(@gig)` it gives me the url `http://gigs/3`,and it works well,it found the gig i need with `id:3` the problem is that it doesn't provide the full url like this

`http://example.com/gigs/3`
P.S. for reference i can do `@gig.title`,`@gig.description` and it works with no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the full URL, use `gig_url(@gig)` instead of `gig_path(@gig)`.

Comment: yes it did work in production,i just checked...but this is very strange instead of going to my custom domain name www.example.com/gigs/3 it goes to my www.herokuapp/gigs/3 ,but to the right one.why is that?

Comment: That's because Rails has no way to reliably figure out on its own what your host name is. Thus, you need to tell it what you want to use by setting the default. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails for details.

Comment: the problem,was that i had a 'config.action_mailer.default_url_options' in production.rb that was redirecting to the heroku url)