# Rails: How to link to static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'd like to do is to link to static pages in Rails.

The page is created in `sample.com/path1/path2/page.html.erb`

How can I link to `page.html.erb`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "link\_to" full path in rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606747/how-to-link-to-full-path-in-rails-4)

Comment: I'd like to know how I can write in `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your routes.rb you should have something like

```
get '/page', to: 'path#page', as: :page
```

where path is the folder where the page file is in

eg

```
get '/page', to: 'layout#page', as: :page
```

then you will link with

```
<li><%= link_to "page", page_path %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I'd like to do is to link to nested folder. How can I link to /page/layout/foobar/index.html?

Comment: then you have something like `get 'page/layout/foobar/index'` in your route