# Rails & Devise. Set my urls generated for password reset to have www

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for my rails project. However I want to make the password reset links that Devise generates to always have "www" before my web address? I am not quite sure how to achieve this.

Any recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide you code for better understanding.

Comment: Is your entire application on the 'www' sub domain? In that case you would do it by setting the host name in default URL options. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660172/544825