# Rails: replace localhost:3000 with custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In development, I would like to replace `localhost:3000` to something like `"domain.com:3000" or "domain.com".` I can achieve this by adding alias to /etc/hosts file, for ex:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   domain.com
```

^^^ this one works, i can now view my site locally using domain.com.

The problem is that rails itself still uses localhost:3000, for example when generating urls via router methods. I feel that there should be some config for this.

Comment: give this a try - https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set default host for url helpers in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails)

Answer (score 4):

You have to set:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'domain.com:3000'
```

in your development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Custom domain name for your IP Address can be created.
First of all find your IP Address using `ifconfig`.
Then open `/etc/hosts` file with `sudo`.

> `/etc/hosts` file is in readonly, so need to open with `sudo`

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

There you will find at least two entries for `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.1.1`, below this, create your own domain name

```
<IP_Address> domain.com
```

Save the file.
Then start your rails server and bind with your IP Address.

```
rails s -b <IP_Address>
```

And you are done.

In browser,
`<IP_Address>:3000` will be same as `domain.com:3000`